# Meaning of the following linux commands

Tags: shell-script, grep, arguments

```
cat "$1" > /tmp/file.$$   2>/tmp/file0.$$
grep "*"  /tmp/file.$$    >/tmp/file0.$$
```

I understood that in the `cat` command, if an error occurs, the error will be shown in `file0.$$` and if it does not, then contents will be shown in `file.$$`. What I don't understand is what `$1` is.

Also what is happening in the `grep` command.

Answer (score 3):

#### cat

The 1st command dumps the output of what I would assume to be a file, `"$1"` into 2 files. Output to STDOUT goes to `/tmp/file.$$` and output to STDERR goes to `/tmp/file0.$$`. The trailing `$$` is the process ID of this script when it's running.

The `"$1"` is a command line argument (`arg1`) that is being passed into this script, such as:

```
 $ script arg1 arg2
```

#### grep

This line finds all the lines that contain a star ("`*`") in the file `/tmp/file.$$` and writes them out to `/tmp/file0.$$`.

Comment: $1 is not a file..it is something else, but i don't know what it is.

Comment: @user50027 - can you insert an edit before it? `echo "$1"`? Also you could run the script like this to see more of what's going on, `bash -x script`.

Comment: i did.echo "$1" show null value..nothing is printed

Comment: @user50027 - try using `od`. for eg. `echo -e "$1" | od -x`.

Comment: @user50027 You need to supply an argument when you call this script/function. `$1` denotes the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

The "$1" is the first argument to your script:

```
bash your_script argument_1 argument_2 ...
```

Then `$1` will be equal to the value of `argument_1`.
It is a good practice to put it into double quotes in order to get the actual value of the argument (shell will skip interpreting the special characters in the argument if there are any).